# Extracting Email Domain in MyPlayground

Tags: xcode, swift, email, dns, extract

I'm developing a chat application. Users will be required to sign up using a university email address.

My app will heavily rely on compartmentalizing users using a `UnivID` (University ID) which will be the `'@'` symbol along with the email domain. For example, if a user signs up using any of the following email addresses : `jsmith@mail.havard.edu, jsmith@havard.edu, or jsmith@student.havard.edu. The UnivID = '@havard.edu'`

I'm new to coding so I hope not to insult your intelligence if this is easy to implement.

Cheers

Comment: What is your question bro?

Comment: Hi sorry for not being clear. I'm looking to create a string = '@domain.edu' regardless if a user signs up with emails such as jsmith@mail.havard.edu, jsmith@student.havard.edu, or jsmith@havard.edu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you actually want everything after the ampersand. If that is the case then this code will work.

```
let example = "jsmith@student.harvard.edu"
let univId = "@" + example.componentsSeparatedByString("@")[1]
// "@student.harvard.edu"
```

If you really only want the last two parts of an extended domain string then this will work.

```
let example = "jsmith@student.harvard.edu"
let domain  = example.componentsSeparatedByString("@")
let parts   = domain.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
let univId  = "@" + parts[parts.count - 2] + "." + parts[parts.count - 1]
// @harvard.edu
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an algorithm I created to parse the domain and extension from an email address. I used a hardcoded list of the most common domain suffixes to help ensure I don't return just the suffix part of the email if it has a 2 part domain suffix, like "co.uk" or "ca.gov".

You would just need to prepend "@" onto the resulting domain for your use case.

```
class func parseDomain(fromEmail email: String) -> String? {
    let suffixList = ["com", "edu", "gov", "int", "mil", "net", "org", "xyz", "biz", "info", "ai", "io", "co", "ly", "eu", "cn", "ru", "nl", "de", "uk"]

    guard let emailDomains = email.components(separatedBy: "@").last else {
        return nil
    }
    let domainParts = emailDomains.components(separatedBy: ".")

    guard domainParts.count >= 2 else {
        return nil
    }

    var domain = domainParts[domainParts.count - 2] + "." + domainParts[domainParts.count - 1]
    let secondLastComponent = domainParts[domainParts.count - 2]
    if suffixList.contains(secondLastComponent) && domainParts.count >= 3 {
        // we want to avoid returning things like co.uk, or com.au,
        // so if the 2nd last component is a common suffix, return the last 3 parts instead.
        domain = domainParts[domainParts.count - 3] + "." + domainParts[domainParts.count - 2] + "." + domainParts[domainParts.count - 1]
    }

    return domain
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Latest 2020, Swift 5.2, XCode 11.4.1

Code that works for all inputs

```
let example = "email_id@gmail.com"
let components = example.components(separatedBy: "@")
if components.count > 1 {
    let domain = components[1]
    // domain has value gmail.com
}
```